# -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Tags: bash, syntax, newline, token

To reset the admin password of SolusVM I am executing [the following command](https://documentation.solusvm.com/display/DOCS/Generate+New+Admin+Password):

```
php /usr/local/solusvm/scripts/pass.php --type=admin --comm=change --username=<ADMINUSERNAME>
```

When doing so, the following error message is printed:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

What is the reason for this problem? I am running the command as root.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The characters '<', and '>', are to indicate a place-holder, you should remove them to read:

```
php /usr/local/solusvm/scripts/pass.php --type=admin --comm=change --username=ADMINUSERNAME
```

Comment: And in case you really need the angle brackets, you should wrap the value within quotes, as e.g. in `git commit --author="John Doe <john@example.com>"`.

Comment: I cannot remove them since I am using them for `nohup: nohup ipfs daemon --enable-gc --routing=none >> ~/.ipfs.out 2>&1 &!`