# java command throwing an error in linux although works fine in windows

Tags: java, bash, shell, command

I am trying to run my java program through bash in a linux system where the command is:

```
java -Dresources=path1 -Dinstance=instance1 -cp ./lib/jar1.jar;./lib/folder1/*;./lib/common/*; lib/folder2/* com.test.host
```

In the host class I am reading some XML files, which has spring beans and I am loading them. This command works perfectly fine in windows. However, when I run this in Bash shell. I get the following exception:

> syntax error near unexpected token newline 'xml version= 1.0 encoding= utf-8'

I tried removing unnecessary spaces in the XML and tried but to no avail.

Comment: On Linux, you need to separate elements of the classpath with `:` (colon), not `;` (semicolon). Though I don't see how that difference would lead to this error, I would recommend you try it. If that doesn't solve it, please provide a [mre].

Comment: The error itself - at a guess - suggests you have an XML file that starts with `<?\nxml version = 1.0 encoding = utf-8` (that is, with a newline after `<?`) instead of `<?xml version = 1.0 encoding = utf-8`.

Comment: I also notice a space before the last element of the classpath (before `lib/folder2/*`). This could also be the problem. Remove that space.

Comment: This is a [bash error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134399/bash-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-newline). Java doesn't even start.

Comment: @Olivier Would the `;` cause bash to execute the following as a statement?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, I think so.

Comment: The command before the `;` (i.e `java`) should have been executed first and should have printed and error and usage.

Comment: You won't get that error with *that* code. The first thing you will see is a Java usage error message since the Java command (which ends with the first `;`) does not receive a class name as an argument (nor a `-jar` arg of course) as @DiegoTorresMilano has said

Comment: @MarkRotteveel -  you are right, after replacing ; (semi-colon)  with the : (colon)  , the command works as intended. Thanks for the info. However, I am not sure why did java not detect the error with the usage and threw an error/exception.

Answer (score 0):

As @MarkRotteveel mentioned, after replacing ; (semi-colon) with the : (colon) , the command works as intended. However, I am not sure why did java not detect the error with the usage and threw an error/exception